# Most elegant way to invoke \parindent but not \parskip when going to next line

Tags: parskip, parindent

As can be seen from the MWE below, we define:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{3em}
```

wherein `parindent` will set a horizontal space of `3em` before the start of a new paragraph, and `parskip` will set a vertical space of `3em` when going to another paragraph.

One can notice the result is the same when inserting a blank line between two "paragraphs" (see **test1**), or inserting `\endgraf` (see **test2**) or inserting `\par` (see **test3**) between them.

As for **test4**, in which `\\` is inserted between the two parts of text (**test4a** and **test4b**), this is not interpreted as a "new paragraph" as one can notice that the second line (**test4b**) received neither the `parindent` nor the `parskip`.

```
       test4a blablabla
test4b blablabla
```

My question is: what is the most elegant way to make **test5a** and **test5b** which will output something as follows:

```
       test5a blablabla
       test5b blablabla
```

That is: to invoke `\parindent` (the second line also has horizontal indentation of `3em`) but not `\parskip` (so that there is no extra vertical separation of `3em`) when going to the next line.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a2paper, fontsize=24pt]{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{3em}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}



test1a blablabla

test1b blablabla
\endgraf



test2 blablabla\endgraf
test2b blablabla
\endgraf



test3a blablabla\par
test3b blablabla
\endgraf



test4a blablabla\\
test4b blablabla

\end{document}
```

## Elegant?

Now, what is meant by **elegant** in this OP?

I am under the impression of having read that it is a "beginner mistake" to want to make WYSIWYG documents in which the formatting/typesetting is already visually to be seen in the code, isn't it? Or at least to do so "to soon". In any way, for my particular purpose, I think something such as

```
       test5a blablabla /command
       test5b blablabla
```

would be ideal, that is to say: the issuing of the command should be as simple as placing `/something` at the end of the line. The text at which `/something` wants to be appended shouldn't need to be placed in any further environment visible in the "body" of the code. Of course it is possible to define the `/command` in the "head" of the code. The "smallest" or "most readable" definition will win.

## Why?

See why I want to use this for example in this PDF [view here](https://github.com/Vincent-Mia-Edie-Verheyen/Traditional-Chinese-reduplicated-words--type-AABB--/blob/master/%E7%96%8A%E9%9F%B3%E8%A9%9E%EF%BC%88%E7%94%B2%E7%94%B2%E4%B9%99%E4%B9%99%E5%BC%8F%EF%BC%89.pdf) or [download here](https://github.com/Vincent-Mia-Edie-Verheyen/Traditional-Chinese-reduplicated-words--type-AABB--/raw/master/%E7%96%8A%E9%9F%B3%E8%A9%9E%EF%BC%88%E7%94%B2%E7%94%B2%E4%B9%99%E4%B9%99%E5%BC%8F%EF%BC%89.pdf). At page 3, where it says `二:` there are indentations which I don't need.

Comment: Why don't you not set parskip to 3em if you don't want any extra space?

Comment: Are you interested in line breaks across the page within your `blablabla`? That is, could you provide more information on the use case of this? It may affect the possible solutions. Also, there is no "most elegant" way, since that's very subjective.

Comment: @Werner There will be no line-breaks within the dummy `blablabla`.

Comment: @Werner There will be no line-breaks within the dummy `blablabla` unless those of the same kind. For example `blablabla BREAK blablabla BREAK blablabla` is possible. With `BREAK` referring to the kind of line-break is asked for in the OP.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen: How about [this paste](https://pastebin.com/cFEp5TUA)?

Comment: @Werner Thank you. That has allowed me to refine my definition of "elegant" in this purpose. Please see the revised OP.

Comment: I guess what you want eill get you in trouble by confusing the TeX engine.

Comment: I have two questions: what's the purpose of setting both `\parindent` and `\parskip` to nonzero values? What should be the reason for a some paragraphs not to be preceded by the parskip?

Comment: why not just set parskip to 0pt? (and use a blank line in the source) that is by far the simplest definition and the intended markup here.

Comment: @egreg Usually I do want indentation of new "paragraphs". But in some cases I have a portion of text which I do not want to start with indentation. I simply want to start a new line. You can interpret it sort of as a listing of items, even though I don't want to use an item environment or something similar.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen You're taking the wrong path, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle See why I want to use this for example in [this PDF](https://github.com/Vincent-Mia-Edie-Verheyen/Traditional-Chinese-reduplicated-words--type-AABB--/raw/master/疊音詞（甲甲乙乙式）.pdf), at page 3, where it says `二:` there are indentations which I don't need.

Comment: if they are paragraphs you should mark them in the source  with a blank line inside some environment that locally has `\parindent` set to 0. You have made me agree with @egreg, a bad way to start the morning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following definition of `\fakepar`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{3em}

\newcommand{\fakepar}{\mbox{}\\\hspace*{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

% Test 1
Lorem ipsum 1a \ldots

Lorem ipsum 1b \ldots

% Test 2
Lorem ipsum 2a \ldots \par
Lorem ipsum 2b \ldots

% Test 3
Lorem ipsum 3a \ldots \endgraf
Lorem ipsum 3b \ldots

% Test 4
Lorem ipsum 4a \ldots \\
Lorem ipsum 4b \ldots

% Test 5
Lorem ipsum 5a \ldots \fakepar
Lorem ipsum 5b \ldots

\end{document}
```

`\fakepar` ensures that *something* is set - `\mbox{}` - before inserting a line break - `\\` - and forcing a regular paragraph indent - `\hspace*{\parindent}`.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason whatsoever for setting a nonzero `\parindent` when `\parskip` is nonzero (I see no reason for setting `\parskip`, except in business letters, actually).

I see no reason either for having “special paragraphs” that are not detached from the previous one, if you choose to set a nonzero parskip.

But the customer's always right, so here is a possible solution, I leave it to you to find where it could go wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\parnoskip}{%
  \par\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \everypar={\the\everypar\noexpand\setlength{\parskip}{\the\parskip}}%
  }\x
  \parskip=0pt
}
%
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{3em}
%

\newcommand{\bla}{some text some text some text some text some text}
\newcommand{\blablabla}{\bla\bla\bla}

\begin{document}

test1a \blablabla

test1b \blablabla

test2 \blablabla\par
test2b \blablabla

test3a \blablabla\parnoskip
test3b \blablabla\parnoskip

test3c \blablabla

\parnoskip

test3d \blablabla

test4a \blablabla

\end{document}
```

As you see, `\parnoskip` can go next to the last word of a paragraph, but also between paragraphs and it can be followed by a blank line.

Don't use `\endgraf` in your documents, except perhaps in some command definition, but never ever in the body.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are more lines placed together then placing `\command` at the end of each line is somewhat impractical. So, IMHO more elegant is to define environment:

```
\def\verse{\begingroup \obeylines \parskip=0pt \relax}
\def\endverse{\par\endgroup}

\verse
first line
second line
next line
last line
\endverse

\bye
```

Comment: `verse` is already defined in LaTeX. Choose another name.

Comment: This is not my problem, this is problem of LaTeX. I don't use it.

Comment: But the questioner does use LaTeX (see the MWE) . If your answer is used in the questioner's (or other's)  LaTeX documents then there is a possibility of problems.